# Conditional probability and instantiation

Tags: conditional-probability

This questions consists of two parts that are quite similar and concern conditional probability.

Firstly, I would like to confirm the calculation of the conditional probability when we know the value of a random variable. Let's assume that we have a conditional matrix which gives us the values for $P(D|A\&B)$ and that B can take the values $(b0, b1)$. If we know that $B = b0$, then if we have to calculate $P(D|A)$, it would just be $P(D|A\&b0)$, right?

Let's now assume that we have a conditional probability matrix giving us $P(F|G\&H)$. If we assume that $F$ is independent from $H$, how can we calculate $P(F|G)$ only using $P(F|G\&H)$?

Comment: You can't, at least not with the information you've given. Even if $F$ and $H$ are (marginally) independent, they may not be conditionally independent given $G$.

Answer (score -1):

According to [the law of total probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability),

$P(F) = \sum_{h} P(F|H=h)$, and 
$P(F|G) = \sum_{h} P(F|G, H=h)$.

The dependency structure does not matter here.

[Here is an example](http://rwchen.com/conditional-independence-and-marginal-independence/) to illustrate marginal vs. conditional independence.

Comment: Err no, the law of total probability does not tell you to add conditional probabilities the way you are showing.